# Is it possible to execute certain commands after bibliography is ended?

Tags: biblatex

I want to execute certain commands after the bibliography typesetting ends. Something similar to `\bibsetup` but intended for commands at the very end of the bibliography

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citecounter=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document} 
    
    Basmah
    
    \cite{aksin}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```

To clarify. Assume we want to provide a table by the end of each chapter reporting entries

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citecounter=true, sorting=ydnt, refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\newcounter{articlenum}
\newcounter{booknum}
\newcounter{lasttwoyears}
\newcounter{lastfiveyears}

\AtEveryBibitem{
    %
    \ifentrytype{article}{%
        \stepcounter{articlenum}%
        }{}%
    %
    \ifentrytype{book}{%
        \stepcounter{booknum}%
    }{}%
}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
    %
    \iffieldint{year}%
    {%
        \ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2004}%
        {%
            \ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2001}%
            {}%
            {\stepcounter{lastfiveyears}}%
        }%
        {\stepcounter{lasttwoyears}}%
    }%
}

\begin{document} 
    
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    
    Basmah
    
    \cite{jcg,sarfraz,kullback:related,matuz:doody,doody}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
    \noindent%
    \begin{NiceTabular}[cell-space-limits=1.1mm]{@{}r >{\color{IndianRed1}}l@{}}
        
        Number of articles is & \thearticlenum
        \\
        
        Number of books is & \thebooknum
        \\
        \addlinespace
        
        Number of references in the last two years is & \thelasttwoyears
        \\
        
        Number of references in the last five years is & \thelastfiveyears
        \\
        
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
    \setcounter{articlenum}{0}
    \setcounter{booknum}{0}
    \setcounter{lasttwoyears}{0}
    \setcounter{lastfiveyears}{0}
    
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\newpage}
    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    \endgroup
    
    Basmah
    
    \cite{jcg,sarfraz,kullback:related,matuz:doody,doody}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
    \noindent%
    \begin{NiceTabular}[cell-space-limits=1.1mm]{@{}r >{\color{IndianRed1}}l@{}}
        
        Number of articles is & \thearticlenum
        \\
        
        Number of books is & \thebooknum
        \\
        \addlinespace
        
        Number of references in the last two years is & \thelasttwoyears
        \\
        
        Number of references in the last five years is & \thelastfiveyears
        \\
        
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

This means that we must reset the counters in all chapters and type the table manually

Comment: ...okay...? Just put it in the code after `\printbibliography[...]` and before `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could be more concrete in your question? What are you trying to achieve? – The rationale of `\bibsetup` (per [manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=122)) is "intended for commands which affect the layout of the bibliography". What are you trying to achieve that cannot be done the intuitive way, by appending your code after the bibliography (as @Werner suggests)?

Comment: I am trying to execute certain code after every bibliography in an automated way. What @Werner says works for documents of single bibliography. For instance, if we got a document with multiple chapters and we want to execute commands all article entries and reporting their number

Answer (score 10):

Generally speaking I would use `\bibsetup` mainly for layout settings (penalties, French/Non-French spacing, ...). These settings are all local. So a direct equivalent of `\bibsetup` for *after* the bibliography makes little sense, as there is no need to reset these layout settings and the following text is not going to be affected due to grouping. (Note that there is a specific hook for font settings called `\bibfont`. Of course the same ideas apply here.)

In order to introduce more arbitrary code that does not necessarily pertain to font and layout settings, I would use `\AtBeginBibliography`. Again, the idea is that code in `\AtBeginBibliography` is mostly local or at least not so problematic that its effects need to be countered directly after the bibliography, so there is no corresponding `\AtEndBibliography` hook. (See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/335 and linked discussions.)

If end code is really needed, at the moment it is easiest to build it into `\defbibenvironment`

```
\defbibenvironment{<name>}{<begin code>}{<end code>}{<item code>}
```

Normally, `<end code>` only holds something like `\endlist`, but you could add more code as well. For example take `authoryear.bbx`'s `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}`

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

You could easily add more stuff after the `\endlist` to execute code after the bibliography list.

---

If I understand your example correctly, however, there is a slightly easier way. `biblatex` allows you to add prenotes and postnotes to the bibliography. These pre-/postnotes should hold typesettable contents and can be used to add a few words directly before or after the bibliography. Together with `\AtBeginBibliography` to reset the counters you can go with

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citecounter=true, sorting=ydnt, refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcounter{articlenum}
\newcounter{booknum}
\newcounter{lasttwoyears}
\newcounter{lastfiveyears}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \setcounter{articlenum}{0}%
  \setcounter{booknum}{0}%
  \setcounter{lasttwoyears}{0}%
  \setcounter{lastfiveyears}{0}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\stepcounter{articlenum}}
    {}%
  \ifentrytype{book}
   {\stepcounter{booknum}}
   {}%
}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldint{year}%
    {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2004}
       {\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2001}
          {}
          {\stepcounter{lastfiveyears}}}
       {\stepcounter{lasttwoyears}}}
    {}%
}

\newcommand*{\statstable}{%
  \begin{NiceTabular}[cell-space-limits=1.1mm]{@{}r >{\color{IndianRed1}}l@{}}
    Number of articles is & \thearticlenum \\
    Number of books is & \thebooknum \\\addlinespace
    Number of references in the last two years is & \thelasttwoyears \\
    Number of references in the last five years is & \thelastfiveyears \\
  \end{NiceTabular}
}
\defbibnote{statstable}{\statstable}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter 1}
  Basmah
  \cite{jcg,sarfraz,kullback:related,matuz:doody,doody}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, postnote=statstable]

  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\newpage}
  \chapter{Chapter 2}
  \endgroup

  Basmah
  \cite{jcg,sarfraz,kullback:related,matuz:doody,doody}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, postnote=statstable]
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations, bibliography list and a small stats table.]

Comment: Really an awesome reply.